# Xamarin.Forms: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am tracking app crashes using app center crashlytics. The stack trace is as follows:

```
    JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, 

Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
Dialog.Show ()
ActivityEx.ShowError (Android.App.Activity activity, System.String title, System.String message)
ActivityEx.ShowError (Android.App.Activity activity, System.String title, System.Exception exception)
WebAuthenticatorActivity.<OnCreate>b__4_1 (System.Object s, Xamarin.Auth.AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs e)
Authenticator+<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<RaiseErrorEvent>b__0 ()
Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run ()
IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this)
(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.47(intptr,intptr)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel InputChannel.java:148
android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay IWindowSession.java:804
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView ViewRootImpl.java:737
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView WindowManagerGlobal.java:359
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView WindowManagerImpl.java:94
android.app.Dialog.show Dialog.java:330
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run RunnableImplementor.java:30
android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread Activity.java:6201
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run RunnableImplementor.java:30
android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:790
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:164
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:6528
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:438
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:807
```

The error is different from the ones that I have seen in this portal. I am not able to figure out what is causing this issue. Need some help regarding this.

Comment: Could you test it on local so that we can get the position in project that caused this issue .

Comment: Finding it difficult to replicate locally or in lower environments. Only happening in prod. I am receiving the following error message - "Error authenticating: server_error" and then authentication error popup is coming multiple times (till the app freezes). Can this popup coming multiple times be a cause for the above issue?

Comment: First you can try download crash report(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/using-the-diagnostics-ui#download-diagnostics-data) to see if it has some clues about where the issue occurs, also, It might be helpful to add some events and enable log flow in your app center project to locate the issue. You can also choose to ask for AppCenter's support on how to locate the issue in AppCenter portal, we can then help with your issue.